# Create Lucene index with encrypted password

Tags: lucene

I am trying to create lucene index using Encryption method , but its throwing the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
org.apache.lucene.store.Directory.openInput(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/lucene/store/IndexInput;
```

What is the wrong in this code?

```
try{  
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    String password = "lucenetrans";
    DataEncryptor enc = new DataEncryptor("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", password, salt, 128,false);
    DataDecryptor dec = new DataDecryptor(password, salt,false);
    indexwriter=new IndexWriter(new TransformedDirectory(FSDirectory.open(outputdir), enc, dec), new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36),true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);
}
catch(Exception ex{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with any class named TransformedDirectory. But, were I to venture a guess, I'd say your problem is probably in there.  Could be a problem with using the wrong version of Lucene.